# NFS home / .profile / 3 flavors of UNIX : best practices?

Tags: unix, shell, nfs, home-directory, .profile

Three flavors of UNIX: Linux, Solaris, IRIX... one NFS mounted home directory.

I'd like to have a (slightly) different .profile behavior based on the OS that I'm connecting to. I can hack something together, but I'd like to not re-invent the wheel if it's not necessary.

Is there a best practice for splitting out .profiles sections based on operating system?

Answer (score 4):

```
#!/bin/sh

case `uname` in
Linux*)
...
esac
```